# Чи можливо за особливостям вимови визначити походження будь-якого українця?

Tags: фонетика

Ще навчаючись у школі я прочитав п'єсу "Пігмаліон", де професор Генрі Хігінс міг за особливостями вимови визначити походження того чи іншого англійця. З того часу я мене все не полишає питання чи можливо звичайному українцеві (а не спеціалсту по фонетиці) також навчитися розрізняти різні діалекти?
У полягають труднощі?

Ну, перш за все, це вибір відповідної літератури, де можна було б ознайомитися із особливостями того чи іншого діалетку. Ось [тут](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um157.htm) мені вдалося знайти назви багатьох робіт по діалектології, однак цікавить чи є якісь конкретні, де були б зібрані основні особливості усіх діалектів?

Крім того, є ще й така проблема, що матеріли подані у джерелах не завжди виявляються вірними. В одній книзі про Україну (на жаль я не пам'ятаю її назви) я прочитав, що на Тернопільщині часто кажут не -ря-, а -ра-, наприклад, не "буряк", а "бурак" тощо. Однак, я ніколи не чув, щоб хтось так казав (а моє рідне містечко знаходиться саме на Тернопільщині).

Власні спостереження також можуть бути оманливі. Якось мені довелося досить багато часу провести у Чернівцях. І я помітив, що буковинці кажуть не "приїжджали", а "приїхали", тобто вони спрощують це "-ждж". З того часу я завжди коли чув, що люди так говорять, то робив припущення, що вони саме з Буковини, однак якось на Закарпатті, мені трапилося почути, що люди так само кажуть "приїхали" замість "приїжджали". Тому можливо користувачам цього сайту відомі, якісь точні особливості того чи іншого діалекту.

Отож, перш за все цікавлять надійні джерела літератури, у яких, якщо це можливо, зібрані усі особливості усі діалектів. А також цікавить відповідь на основне питання - чи можливо таки визначити походження будь-якого українця за його говором?

Comment: Не упевнений, що такі запитання відповідають формату SE. Як мінімум, варто прибрати запрошення до «власних спостережень користувачів», що є opinion-based.

Comment: Мався на увазі досвід (бо можливо хтось із користувачів і справді спеціаліст по фонетиці), однак, якщо ви так вважаєте, я заберу цю частину запитання.

Comment: Ось [напрьам](http://www.slavatlas.org/publications.html), дальі справа за вами.

Comment: Дякую, а можливо ви можете порадити ще й якісь матеріали українською?

Answer (score 2):

Це не є офіційною відповіддю,скоріше просто власним спостереженням. За все своє коротеньке життя я була в багатьох частинах України та змогла виокремити лише декілька особливостей мовлення місцевих. Це стосується не тільки вимови окремих слів, а й загалом швидкості та мінливості тону. Наприклад, жителі сходу частіше говорили,різко вимовляючи звуки. В їхній вимові виразно вчувався вплив російської. У центрі (де,між іншим знаходиться моє рідне містечко) вимова пом'якшена, подекуди навіть занадто (Ці трикляті "га" та "шо")  також,  я помітила,що в нас чіткіша,ніж в інших частинах України, межа між мешканцями міст і сіл. Люди,що приїхали в місто з села, вирізняються специфічною вимовою, за якої слова вимовляються ніби по складах і часто в одній тональності, ненадовго перескакуючи на вищу чи нижчу. В центрі це чомусь виявляється набагато сильніше,ніж будь-де в Україні. В західній частині взагалі багато цікавих мовних особливостей які я досі  не можу описати цілком, наприклад вживання таких висловів як "буду йшов". Таке я часто чула на Закарпатті в селі, в якому живуть мої знайомі. Не впевнена,що можливо точно розрізнити походження людини за вимовою слів чи діалектом, проте швидкість вимови,перепади тону голосу, паузи та чіткість вимови все ж дають свої підказки.